# Using wpdb for querying Wordpress Custom Table - Can't find the error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code on wordpress. It does not return results or return an error. I don't know where I am making a mistake. Kindly help

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->course_names");

foreach ($results as $result){
echo $result->Course_Sub_ID.'<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Leo. That was fast.. but still, no results or errors returned.
Regards.

Comment: Can you show us what var_dump( $results ) output?

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme2\page-about-us.php:31:null

Comment: If your `$results` variable is `null` it could mean your query has no results. Var_dump the query before you execute it to see what you are really running and maybe double check with your DB that the query is valid.

Comment: @Zsram, thanks, the Null returned made me rethink my sql statement.@Kimberly. Thanks. Just as you pointed- the DB query - I copied the sql statement from the phpMyAdmin and paste in my code and it work. A closer look at why I was having not results or error returned showed that my table name had vertical single quote sign instead of the backward single quote sign around the table name.
Thanks to all you guys.

Comment: @CharlesO, where in your code you had to change vertical quotes for back quotes? Anyway, I am glad you solved your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not expert in wordpress, but looking your code I see your variable $wpdb has not been initialized. A global variable in PHP means that it can be accesed from functions within the same PHP program, but not throughout a session. I guess you are missing something like an include. Perhaps:

```
include_once 'wp-load.php';
include_once 'wp-includes/wp-db.php';
```

You need to find out where that file is and add a proper path to them.
Also, normally $result will be an array, so you have to consider too a previous answer (deleted now) from another user for printing your result within the foreach:

```
echo $result['Course_Sub_ID'], '<br>';
```

Look this example: https://gist.github.com/benbalter/1607991

I hope that helps.